# Very poor quality ad for DevCon5

Tags: discussion, advertising

I don't know if this is the kind of thing that we can do anything about, but the ad I just saw for DevCon5 looks like they printed it out, crumpled it up, laid it on a table, and took a picture with a cell phone camera.

:[image: blurry devCon ad]

ETA: follow-up; here's the new version.  Still not that great, but definitely better

[image: better devCon ad]

Comment: They are perhaps celebrating the 15th anniversary of the 1996 era of inkjet printers.

Comment: Heh yeah, I saw that and thought it was a scan from a wet magazine.

Comment: It might be crappy quality, but it got your attention, didn't it? MISSION ACCOMPLISHED.

Comment: Well, I doubt I would have gone anyway; I don't really want to exude form and function.  It sounds uncomfortable.

Comment: what? no wood grain visible around the edges of the picture? Could be failer...

Comment: You should totally drop that and try DevDays 2011.

Answer (score 18):

Interesting. It turned out the source file being used for this ad had more than one sized rendering in the image file. When viewed standalone, the image looked as intended. However, when viewed in the browser (some browsers? all browsers?) within the div for the sidebar ad on the page, the browser was taking the smaller thumbnail version and scaling it up to the full size of the div. End Result: Yuck!

We've since updated the image file on the ad server to include only the full resolution rendering. The ad should now appear correctly.

Thanks for the catch!

Comment: +1 because you have lowest reputation among ♦ next to Community User. ;)

Comment: hah, yes, thanks for the nod....although my SO reputation is quite a bit more respectable, especially for somebody with "VP" in their title :)